# Быстрый переход по изображениям вконтакте. Как работает?

Tags: ajax, javascript, вконтакте

Когда просматриваю фотографии вконтакте, они просматриваются, можно сказать, **моментально** (то есть я кликнул "следующая" и вот она уже открыта, никаких задержек). При этом браузер явно загрузил новую страницу, плюс сменил адрес.

Сначала думал, что просто ajax-ом подгружается сразу несколько, и они листаются, но ведь нет. Адрес меняется, страница загружается. Как это происходит так быстро?

Заглянул в код, там мало что понятно мне (я плохо разбираюсь в javascript). В общем, увидел ajax.post. Ну ок, ajax, но ведь страница грузится, адрес меняется. Ajax-ом такого не сделать. Непонятно.

Кто знает, объясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Костя Земцовский, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

1. "Моментально" - это вам кажется... Скорее это превентивная ( опережающая ) подгрузка изображений
2. Загрузка идёт аля AJAX
3. Перехода по страницам нет - это History API или якори, в зависимости от браузера.

Comment: Спасибо.
Почитаю про History API. Не знал о такой штуке